# C macros with operator explanation

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, glib

I'm wondering how operator passing into macros works. They are macros from glib sources (`glib/testutils.h`).

In code you are using assert as `g_assert_cmpint(1, ==, 2);`, so operator just passed as is. How it works? What does `#` token mean in this macro?

```
#define g_assert_cmpint(n1, cmp, n2)                  \
  G_STMT_START {                                      \
    gint64 __n1 = (n1), __n2 = (n2);                  \
    if (__n1 cmp __n2) ;                              \
    else                                              \
      g_assertion_message_cmpnum(                     \
        G_LOG_DOMAIN, __FILE__, __LINE__, G_STRFUNC,  \
        #n1 " " #cmp " " #n2, __n1, #cmp, __n2, 'i'); \
  } G_STMT_END
```

and `g_assert_message_cmpnum` has such interface:

```
void g_assertion_message_cmpnum(const char *domain, \
                                 const char *file,\
                                 int line,\
                                 const char func,\
                                 const char *expr,\
                                 long double arg1, \
                                 const char *cmp,\
                                 long double arg2,\
                                 char numtype);
```

does this mean that `#` converts `cmp` operator to a string?

But then how to understand this line `#n1 " " #cmp " " #n2` from a macro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes `#` in the preprocessor is "stringification".

Then, in a later phase after preprocessing, all adjacent string literals are joined into one big string.

Answer (score 3):

Because macros are processed before compile time (preprocessor stage). So it would simply "replaced" cmp with the passed operator.
Using "macros" is unsafed because it doesn't perform type checked.

Example bellow:

```
#define DOUBLE(x) x << 1 /// shift 1 bit left = multiple by 2

cout << DOUBLE(5) << endl; /// result "51" instead of "10" 
/// because the result of processed code is:
cout << 5 << 1 << endl;
```

Comment: The OP is going to have a tough time getting `cout` and `endl` to work in C. (the rest of your answer I agree with)

Comment: This is not an answer.